# Validation Accuracy remains constant while training VGG?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, tensorflow

I posted this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66503501/validation-accuracy-remains-constant-while-training-vgg) and got downvoted for unmentioned reason, so I'll repost it here, hoping to get some insights

This is the plot
[image]

This is the code:

```
with strategy.scope():

  model2 = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(
    include_top=True,
    weights=None,
    input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=(32, 32, 3),
    pooling=None,
    classes=10,
    classifier_activation="relu",
  )

  model2.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
  
  history = model2.fit(
            train_images, train_labels,epochs=10, 
            validation_data=(test_images, test_labels)
            )
```

I'm trying to train VGG16 from scratch, hence not importing their weights I also tried a model which I created myself, with same hyperparameters, and that worked fine

Any help is highly appreciated

[Heres](https://gist.github.com/SadafShafi/d55d20df6c2f7586bf211476fedee950) the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem
The simple thing was that learning rate was too big
I changed the code to this

```
LR = batch_size/((z+1)*100000)
LR=LR/3
```

instead of

```
LR = batch_size/((z+1)*1000)
LR=LR/3
```

and it seems to work well

Comment: The question still remains that why does it show decent accuracy in case of training and not in validation when the learning rate is too high